# How to Show Videos as a Desktop Background (in XP)?

Tags: c#, video, windows-xp, desktop-background

Is it possible to display videos as a desktop background in XP programmatically, preferably using C#? VLC can do it, via its "DirectX > Enable Wallpaper Mode", so it may be possible to do this through the VLC command line interface. Can anyone recommend a way of doing this?

Comment: It's a programming question...Read it carefully.

Comment: Winamp must use a similar feature to support full screen visualisations on the desktop.  Not sure if that's any help, however :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the [Active Desktop](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000593.htm) feature and point it to a web page playing a video (through the Media Plyer ActiveX control, or through Flash).

Comment: I've tried it, and it sort of works. The problem is trying to change the background html file without it flickering OR somehow communicating with the javascript used in html file (which seems impossible). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't give up so easily. You can have a JavaScript block in the page interacting with an external file, let's say a .json or .xml, to get the parameters you want to change (video file name, size, etc.). Then all you have to do is change the contents of the file, trigger an event in the script (let's say, click a corner of your screen, or have it occur on timer) - and there you go. Good luck!